# How can capabilities be set for a file across upgrades in dpkg like for permissions with dpkg-statoverride

Tags: linux, debian, dpkg

My goal is to set permanent file capabilities for a file in Debian that is managed by dpkg.
Permissions can be set with dpkg-statoverride but this does not work for cababilities.

I search a tool, I already know how to do it with hook, but it seams me not to be very clean.

Maybe this is not implemented yet.

nullpointer

Answer (score 0):

Neither the Debian package format nor `dpkg` provide a way to specify capabilities in the package, so there isn't an easy way to do what you want.

There are Debian packages, such as `iputils-ping`, which set the package to use capabilities in the `postinst` script.  Doing it in a similar way is probably the best way forward.  Do note that using the `setcap` command requires that the `libcap2-bin` package is installed and it also requires that the file system support extended attributes, which not all do.  You may need to choose a fallback mechanism as well if your package will run on machines that aren't tightly controlled.

Comment: Thanks it helps, but I am not developing a package. I just want to change the defaults of installed packages. But the if I understand it right there is no other way to do it.

Comment: Yes, there isn't.